# "Authentication failed" when creating a key using the TPM / TrouSerS API

Tags: tpm

I'm attempting to sign some data using the TPM through the TrouSerS API. I have scoured the web for code examples and the only one I've come across is in slide #30 of [this PDF](https://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/Intro-to-Using-the-TSS-2005-11-07.pdf) (the TPM and Trousers have notoriously cryptic documentation, in my opinion).

The code fails when I call the following function to create a signing key:

> Tspi_Key_CreateKey()

The error code I obtain is "1", which when run through the `Trspi_Error_String()` function translates to the string "Authentication failed". Clearly, the call to create the signing key fails because it does not have the right authorization policy.

In the code sample below you can see that I'm setting the default policy secret to be `TSS_WELL_KNOWN_SECRET`, which is twenty 0's if I recall correctly. I haven't been able to find good documentation on how policies operate and how to make sure my calls to the TPM are authorized. I need help understanding two things:

- How do policies work in TrouSerS and the TPM?
- How do I make sure that my call to `Tspi_Key_CreateKey()` is authorized?

```cpp
TSS_HCONTEXT hContext;
TSS_HKEY hSigningKey, hSRK;
TSS_HPOLICY hPolicy;
BYTE secret[] = TSS_WELL_KNOWN_SECRET;

// Init context and connect to tcsd daemon
Tspi_Context_Create(&hContext);
Tspi_Context_Connect(hContext, NULL);

// Create object for Software Root Key
Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_RSAKEY, TSS_KEY_TSP_SRK, &hSRK);

// Create object for signing key
Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_RSAKEY,
                    TSS_KEY_TYPE_SIGNING |
                    TSS_KEY_SIZE_2048 |
                    TSS_KEY_AUTHORIZATION |
                    TSS_KEY_NOT_MIGRATABLE,
                    &hSigningKey);

// Set up the default policy, which applies to all objects
Tspi_Context_GetDefaultPolicy(hContext, &hPolicy);
Tspi_Policy_SetSecret(hPolicy, TSS_SECRET_MODE_SHA1, 20, secret);

// Load the SRK key
TSS_UUID SRK_UUID = TSS_UUID_SRK;
Tspi_Context_LoadKeyByUUID(hContext, TSS_PS_TYPE_SYSTEM, SRK_UUID, &hSRK);

// Create the signing key
Tspi_Key_CreateKey(hSigningKey, hSRK, 0);
if (result != TSS_SUCCESS) {
    LOG(ERROR) << "Failed to create signing key " << result;
    LOG(ERROR) << Trspi_Error_String(result);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of not reading more into the TPM documentation for my particular system (a Google Chromebook). As the [documentation says](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/release-R66-10452.B/cryptohome/README.tpm#18), Chromebooks set the SRK password to NULL. Adjusting my code to use this secret made the call to `Tspi_Key_CreateKey()` return successfully. From there I was able to sign a bit of data and verify the signature. You can find the adjusted code below:

```cpp
TSS_HCONTEXT hContext;
TSS_HKEY hSigningKey, hSRK;
TSS_HPOLICY hPolicy;
BYTE secret[] = {}; // NOTE: Secret is now empty

// Init context and connect to tcsd daemon
Tspi_Context_Create(&hContext);
Tspi_Context_Connect(hContext, NULL);

// Create object for Software Root Key
Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_RSAKEY, TSS_KEY_TSP_SRK, &hSRK);

// Create object for signing key
Tspi_Context_CreateObject(hContext, TSS_OBJECT_TYPE_RSAKEY,
                    TSS_KEY_TYPE_SIGNING |
                    TSS_KEY_SIZE_2048 |
                    TSS_KEY_AUTHORIZATION |
                    TSS_KEY_NOT_MIGRATABLE,
                    &hSigningKey);

Tspi_Context_GetDefaultPolicy(hContext, &hPolicy);
Tspi_Policy_SetSecret(hPolicy, TSS_SECRET_MODE_PLAIN, 0, secret); // NOTE: Using TSS_SECRET_MODE_PLAIN now

// Load the SRK key
TSS_UUID SRK_UUID = TSS_UUID_SRK;
Tspi_Context_LoadKeyByUUID(hContext, TSS_PS_TYPE_SYSTEM, SRK_UUID, &hSRK);

// Create the signing key
Tspi_Key_CreateKey(hSigningKey, hSRK, 0);
```